# How to send update SQLite table from one to everyother

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 users in my app.
1) Normal user
2) Admin

The admin can perform certain changes in the app which update my SQL table stored. Once this update is done how do I make it affect the users who aren't admins?

I'm guessing this will have something to do with a server but how?

EDIT:
Its an app that holds data of what classes are going on in different classrooms in different buildings. So I'm storing all that data in a table. so now if the admin wants to change something I make that changes in the table accordingly. But this change will happen locally on his device. How do I make it appear for all other devices?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of app you're talking about. Is the admin you're talking about someone that admins the phone/tablet or some kind of admin that sets data up and the phone wants to get it from the Internet or...?

Comment: Its an app that holds data of what classes are going on in different classrooms in different buildings. So I'm storing all that data in a table. so now if the admin wants to change something I make that changes in the table accordingly. But this change will happen locally on his device. How do I make it appear for all other devices?

Comment: In that case, yes, you'll have to upload it to a server and have the other phones check it for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you have to make a web server and migrate the database to that server, and all the users can access the database from there. And to reflect updates to every user, u can implement 2 methods:

1. The users will poll the server at regular intervals to check if there is any change in the database
2. u can use GCM, i.e. Google Cloud Messaging to directly send notifications to all users as soon as the database is updated.

While the first method is easy to implement, it could eat up bandwidth of the user as regular checks consume more data.

The second method is lengthy to implement, but it saves up a lot of bandwidth.Also, GCM works only on android devices, so it kind of redeces the scalability of the pp to only the android platform.